# How to customize the update functionality in ColdFusion ORM?

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I want to customize the update function of ORM. By default, ORM loads the object that needs to be updated, makes updates, and then saves the object. I want to update a record when a certain condition is satisfied.

For example :

[image]

I want to update payment mode from **credit card** to **cash**. Before updating records I want to check that I already have a **cash** payment mode. If one exists then I do not need to update a record otherwise update the record.

For the above checking I have used this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM hr_lookup_paymentmode 
WHERE PaymentMode = 'cash' 
  AND modeid <> '10'
```

Equivalent HQL:

```
/**
    * @hint Determines total number of results with same value of search for update purposes.
    */
remote numeric function searchUpdateCount(string q,numeric modeid ) output="false" {

var hqlString = "";
var whereClause = "";
var params = {};
hqlString = hqlString & "SELECT count(*) ";
hqlString = hqlString & "FROM hr_lookup_paymentmode";
if (len(arguments.q) gt 0)
{
    whereClause  = ListAppend(whereClause, " PaymentMode = '#arguments.q#'", "|");
    whereClause  = ListAppend(whereClause, "modeid <> '#arguments.modeid#'", "|");
    whereClause = Replace(whereClause, "|", " AND ", "all");

}


if (len(whereClause) gt 0){
    hqlString = hqlString & " WHERE " & whereClause;
}
return ormExecuteQuery(hqlString, false, params)[1];
}
```

Parameter `q = 'cash'` and `modeid = 10`. If count found is greater than 0 means record already exists, otherwise go for update.

Please help me apply this logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ORM event handlers - either globally defined or defined in specific ORM objects. [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSDD377092-70D9-4b11-A19C-505F59EE31D1.html) is some information on event handlers, but basically you would do the following in your ORM object:

```
function preUpdate( obj, data ){
   {do stuff here }
}
```

In this example `obj` is the ORM entity you are trying to save and `data` is a structure containing the old data from the ORM entity. You would simply add your logic to the body of the function.